# CLIPS subset duplicate values

Tags: subset, clips

I want to have a rule that suggests the possible item combinations in a player's inventory.

Below are some example facts. Item facts contain the recipe for item combinations and the player facts contain the items in the player's inventory.

```
(player (name x) (inventory "aaa" "bbb" "ccc"))

(item (name xxx) (recipe "aaa" "bbb"))
(item (name yyy) (recipe "aaa" "aaa" "ccc"))
```

Below is the rule I have written:

```
; ; Item Combination rule
(defrule item-combination
    (player (name ?n1) (inventory $?i1))
    (item (name ?n2) (recipe $?i2))
    (test (subsetp $?i2 $?i1))
    =>
    (assert (can-combine ?n1 ?n2))
)
```

The rule works well if there are no duplicate items in the recipe.

For example, for item yyy, we need 2 instances of "aaa", however (subsetp (aaa aaa ccc) (aaa bbb ccc)) will return true. However, I require that there contain 2 instances of "aaa" in the player's inventory.

I wonder if there is a function to check subset that involves duplicate values.

EDIT: I have written my own function

```
(deffunction subsetdp (?sub ?set) 
    (if (eq 0 (length$ ?sub)) 
        then (return TRUE))
    (bind ?x (member$ (nth$ 1 ?sub) ?set))
    (if ?x 
        then (return (subsetdp (rest$ ?sub) (delete$ ?set ?x ?x))))
    FALSE)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write your own function as you have done if you want to check for duplicates.